# NodeJS return response output to array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a function in my server side which returns the results from database.
Here's the function

```
    const sql = 
   `SELECT addresses
    FROM  Addresses
    WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(addresses, '$.address') LIKE ? `

  const values = ['"'+beginning+'%']

  const query = connection.query(sql, values, (error, results, fields) => {

      connection.end()
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      }
      resolve(results)
    })
  })
    .then((results) => {

      return {
        type: 'address',
        attributes: results

      }
    })
```

It's output is like this

```
    {
  "data": {
    "type": "address",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "addresses": "{\"address\": \"5 street, auburn, nsw 2144\", \"display\": \"5-7 Mary Street, AUBURN, NSW 2144\"}"
      },
      {
        "addresses": "{\"address\": \"5 street, lidcombe, nsw 2141\", \"display\": \"5 Street, LIDCOMBE, NSW 2141\"}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm new to JS and I need to make the above output as follows

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "address",
      "id": "5-13 aubrey street, granville, nsw 2142",
      "attributes": {
        "address": "5-13 aubrey street, granville, nsw 2142",
        "display": "5-13 Aubrey Street, GRANVILLE, NSW 2142"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "address",
      "id": "5 street, lidcombe, nsw 2141",
      "attributes": {
        "address": "5 street, lidcombe, nsw 2141",
        "display": "5 Street, LIDCOMBE, NSW 2141"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "address",
      "id": "5-7 mary street, auburn, nsw 2144",
      "attributes": {
        "address": "5-7 mary street, auburn, nsw 2144",
        "display": "5-7 Mary Street, AUBURN, NSW 2144"
      }
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me to change .then((results) body of my function to make this happen.

In the client side I'm getting the results inside a function and this is how I return it

```
      return $http.get(`${API_URL}/addresses/?beginning=${searchTerm || ''}`)
  .then((result) => {

    // Only want to return the address string

    return result.data.data((address) => address.attributes.display)
  })
```

But I'm getting result.data.data is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the return to be

```
return {
    type: 'address',
    attributes: results.map(result => JSON.parse(result.addresses))
}
```

Comment: From the client side after calling the API , I'm trying to get results as 
 return result.data((address) => address.attributes.display)

but it's not working. Can you help me to match this to above answer?

Comment: @kavish i am not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, can you explain ?

Comment: Thank you a lot for replying. I updated the question. please check the last part 'in my client side..

Comment: @kavish you have to call `map`, like `return result.data.data.map((address) => address.attributes.display)`